# unable to install PyDev for Eclipse Release 2(4.4.2)

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I just downloaded and installed eclipse, I now want to install PyDev and it's failing, I get an error message:

HTTP Server Unknown HTTP Response Code (302):http://www.pydev.org/updates/content.xml
General connection error with response code=302

is there another to install it? I'm trying to install it from the market place via eclipse

Answer (score 1):

When attempting to download Pydev from Eclipse marketplace; Eclipse marketplace is currently using the following link: http://www.pydev.org/updates/

This is not a direct link and will result in an installation failure in some cases, such as mine and others.

What to do:

In Eclipse go to Help > Install New Software > Add >

Now add a name example: "Pydev.
Select the link below and choose the version of pydev you want to install.
http://dl.bintray.com/fabioz/pydev/

Copy the entire link to the version you have chosen ex. http://dl.bintray.com/fabioz/pydev/7.5.0/
and paste it in the Eclipse Add Repository "Location:" field.

Please note: The above link does not use a secure connection "https". Using a secure transfer connection may result in failure, such as in my case.

Answer (score 0):

For older versions of Eclipse, you need to access older versions of the update site.

The update site urls may be seen at: http://www.pydev.org/update_sites

And you may visit http://www.pydev.org/download.html to know which version of PyDev you need (search for `Need to use older Eclipse/Java/Python` in that page).